# How to set timestamp on row during insert/update

Tags: intersystems-cache

I want to set a timestamp column every time a field is updated or inserted via SQL.

I tried using a SqlComputed property, but that has the unwanted side of effect of setting the field when I %Open or %New and object in ObjectScript, if the field is initially null. I don't want the value to be set until the object is %Save'd (or INSERT'ed/UPDATE'd).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the property is transient or calculated then the SQLComputed calculation will run every time the value is retrieved.  If the property is neither then the calculation will be run upon modification and be stored in the database, which is what you are looking for.

Comment: I thought this is what I was looking for, but if the value is null, the calculation is getting run when the record is %Open'ed. Maybe this is a bug in Caché 2008.1.

Comment: @Marc Can you send the .INT code where this happens?  I can't replicate in 2008.2, which is as close as I can get.  I'm using a %Library.TimeStamp property.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the SQLCompute On Change.  Based on your described case I think you want to define it as %%INSERT,%%UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can get a clue from the following example. %OnBeforeSave is called whenever you try to call %Save() method using COS. Just note that this method is not called when you use 'insert' or 'update' using SQL tho.

```
Property LastModified As %Date;
Property RegDate As %Date;
/// 
/// This callback method is invoked by the <METHOD>%Save</METHOD> method to 
/// provide notification that the object is being saved. It is called before 
/// any data is written to disk.
/// 
/// <P><VAR>insert</VAR> will be set to 1 if this object is being saved for the first time.
/// 
/// <P>If this method returns an error then the call to <METHOD>%Save</METHOD> will fail.
Method %OnBeforeSave(insert As %Boolean) As %Status [ Private ]
{

    if insert s ..RegDate=$h
    s ..LastModified = $h
    quit $$$OK
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the class, you can update the property to have an InitialExpression like the below:

```
Property CreateTimeStamp As %TimeStamp [ InitialExpression = {$ZDateTime($H,3)} ];
```